# How to download a file directly from a cloud service to an attached USB drive?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, cloud

I need to download a video file (700MB) from the cloud service Bitcasa to a USB flash drive but right now when I click "Download" in Bitcasa my only options are to download to the my S6 phone & then copy it to my USB key. Is there a shorter way? I can't seem to find a way to download directly on to the flash drive...is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

[An OTG cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009DFCCKO/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=569136327&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B000EORX7U&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=H099K5DHP2595SD0VKF6) would be a way to do it.

Comment: What is the difference? My USB is plugged in to the micro phone port already! Why does using a cable instead help?

Comment: It wasn't clear you wanted that. I take it you've been able to transfer files in that way in the past?

Comment: First time using a micro drive! 

Comment: I just don't get why I can't choose the USB to download to instead of some random internal storage folder. Why is the cloud service restricting that? Any way to override this?

Comment: What file structure has it been formatted with? NTFS? FAT32?

Comment: The USB? How do I find out? Bought a 64GB Kingston one.

Comment: A movie I loaded on the USB plays fine from the USB to on my MX Player on my phone...so does it have to be formatted? What is the purpose of formatting?

Comment: FAT32 is the size that fits all and generally advised for best compatibility.



`"Your USB drive should ideally be formatted with the FAT32 file system for maximum compatibility. Some Android devices may also support the exFAT file system. No Android devices will support Microsoft’s NTFS file system, unfortunately."`

Comment: But how do I know what formatting my drive has?  I'm doing all this on my phone. Not using a computer.

Comment: [Hopefully this should answer some questions](http://www.howtogeek.com/129800/how-to-use-usb-drives-with-the-nexus-7-and-other-android-devices/).